# How to add “jQuery” onclick functionality for a column each row in jQgrid to display different popups for different rows

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Index</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css">
 <link href="css/cerulean.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 37.5em)" type="text/css">
 <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css">
 <link href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css">
 <link href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css">
 <script type='text/javascript' src="js/respond.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
 <script src="js/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
 /////////////////UPCOMING RECORD DATE/////////////////     
 $(function () {
      'use strict';
      var mydata = [{cusip: "<a href='#'>1234567890123456</a>", oid_type: "F", oid_type_desc: "Federal/Agency STRIP"},                                                             {cusip: "<a href='#'>1234567890123456</a>", oid_type: "S", oid_type_desc: "Taxable STRIP not backed by a federal/agency bond"}],
      $grid = $("#myOID"),  
      viewParam = { 
          bSubmit: "Save and Close",
          recreateForm: true,
          beforeShowForm: function ($form){
          $form.find("td.DataTD").each(function () {
          var html = $(this).html();  // &nbsp;<span>&nbsp;</span>
          if (html.substr(0, 6) === "&nbsp;") {
               $(this).html(html.substr(6));
          }
      });
      }};
      $grid.jqGrid({
          datatype: 'local',
          data: mydata,
          colNames: ["CUSIP", "OID Code", "OID Type Description"],
          colModel: [
          {name: 'cusip', align: 'left', width: 120, sorttype: 'text', index: 'cusip'},
          {name: 'oid_type', align: 'left', width: 90, sorttype: 'text', index: 'oid_type'},
          {name: 'oid_type_desc', align: 'left', width: 440, sorttype: 'text', index: 'oid_type_desc'},
          ],
          rowNum: 15,
          rowList: [15],
          pager: '#pager1',
          gridview: true,
          autoWidth: true,
          //editable: true,
          rownumbers: false,
          //  onSelectRow: function (id) {
          //        $(this).jqGrid('viewGridRow', id, viewParam);
          //   },
          sortname: 'invdate',
          viewrecords: false,
          sortorder: 'desc',
          width: 650,
          shrinkToFit: false,
          height:"auto"
      });
    });
    /////////////////UPCOMING RECORD DATE ENDS/////////////////  



                                            </script>

            </head>

            <body>

            <div class="row" id='oid_index_jqgrid'>
                                        <div class="col-xs-6 oid_index_jqgrid_col">
                                       <div class="col-md-6 oid_index_jqgrid">
                                                    <table id="myOID"></table>
                                                <div id="pager1"></div> 
                                                </div>
                                      </div>

                                    </div>


    <div class="modal fade" id='PIK'>
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">PIK</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form role="form">
            <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                   <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="selectUser" class="CUSIP_PageTitle Inner_Titles">Bond Unit Factor</label>
                    <select class="form-control CUSIP_Form_Control">
                      <option>A</option>
                      <option>B</option>
                      <option>C</option>
                      <option>D</option>
                      <option>E</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="selectUser" class="CUSIP_PageTitle Inner_Titles">PIK Rate</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control CUSIP_Text_Input">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="selectUser" class="CUSIP_PageTitle Inner_Titles">Cash Rate</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control CUSIP_Text_Input">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="selectUser" class="CUSIP_PageTitle Inner_Titles">Payment Mode</label>
                    <select class="form-control CUSIP_Form_Control">
                      <option>Cash</option>
                      <option>Bonds</option>
                      <option>Bankruptcy</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default popup_close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id='GIK'>
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">PIK</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form role="form">
            <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                   <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="selectUser" class="CUSIP_PageTitle Inner_Titles">Bond Unit Factor</label>
                    <select class="form-control CUSIP_Form_Control">
                      <option>A</option>
                      <option>B</option>
                      <option>C</option>
                      <option>D</option>
                      <option>E</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="selectUser" class="CUSIP_PageTitle Inner_Titles">PIK Rate</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control CUSIP_Text_Input">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="selectUser" class="CUSIP_PageTitle Inner_Titles">Cash Rate</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control CUSIP_Text_Input">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="selectUser" class="CUSIP_PageTitle Inner_Titles">Payment Mode</label>
                    <select class="form-control CUSIP_Form_Control">
                      <option>Cash</option>
                      <option>Bonds</option>
                      <option>Bankruptcy</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default popup_close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->

    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

In the above Html, I have a jQgrid table. I am very new to jQuery and my jQgrid table is working fine. But what I need is I kept different popups in this html. So if I click on some "row" in the column named as "CUSIP", some particular popup with unique 'id' should be displayed. I am not understanding how to write the 'onclick' functionality for this. Could anybody help me please. Remember that What I need is each row in 'CUSIP' column has different popup with a unique id, so how to write a 'onclick' function with a 'id' for each cell. I kept 2 bootstrap popups with different id's in this. each should be displayed by clicking on different rows.

Comment: please use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for long codes

Comment: 1) Isolate the code above so it only shows the code involved in the issue. 2) If you can show an example replicating the issue, you will get more help. 3) Smile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        /////////////////UPCOMING RECORD DATE/////////////////

        $(function () {
            'use strict';
            var mydata = [
                    {cusip: "<a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#TIPS'1234567890123</a>", oid_type: "F", oid_type_desc: "TIPS"},
                    {cusip: "<a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#NQSI'1234567890</a>", oid_type: "S", oid_type_desc: "NQSI"},
                    {cusip: "<a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#TIPS'1234567</a>", oid_type: "C", oid_type_desc: "CPDI"}

                ],
                $grid = $("#myOID"),
                viewParam = {
                    bSubmit: "Save and Close",
                    recreateForm: true,
                    beforeShowForm: function ($form){
                        $form.find("td.DataTD").each(function () {
                            var html = $(this).html();  // &nbsp;<span>&nbsp;</span>
                            if (html.substr(0, 6) === "&nbsp;") {
                                $(this).html(html.substr(6));
                            }

                        });
                    }
                };

            $grid.jqGrid({
                datatype: 'local',
                data: mydata,
                colNames: ["CUSIP", "OID Code", "OID Type Description"],
                colModel: [
                    {name: 'cusip', align: 'left', width: 120, sorttype: 'text', index: 'cusip'},
                    {name: 'oid_type', align: 'left', width: 90, sorttype: 'text', index: 'oid_type'},
                    {name: 'oid_type_desc', align: 'left', width: 440, sorttype: 'text', index: 'oid_type_desc'},
                ],
                rowNum: 15,
                rowList: [15],
                pager: '#pager1',
                gridview: true,
                autoWidth: true,
                //editable: true,
                rownumbers: false,
              //  onSelectRow: function (id) {
            //        $(this).jqGrid('viewGridRow', id, viewParam);
             //   },
                sortname: 'invdate',
                viewrecords: false,
                sortorder: 'desc',
                width: 650,
                shrinkToFit: false,
                height:"auto"
            });
        });
        /////////////////UPCOMING RECORD DATE ENDS/////////////////  



        </script>
```

This is the final answer...I got 100% result

Comment: Here the 'ID' which I have given for 'data-target' can be changed as per the ID which you have given for your 'modal dialog window'.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the alert in the showDialog function for your dialog logic this should work for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/DwQj3UUFrzg0rYvl57ny

I have removed the "key" property from the columns collection and have also removed the option:
    gridview = true
from the grid options.

Comment: Actually What I need is each cell in 'CUSIP' column has different popup with a unique id, so how to write a 'onclick' function with a 'id' for each cell.

Comment: can anybody give me a answer for this...

Comment: I am not understanding what is the jquery function I have to write for 'onclick'

Comment: I will upload a plunker for this later today so you can see it all working.

Comment: can u see my new question on this where I edited the code and also clearly mentioned what exactly I need.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24258540/how-to-write-onclick-function-for-different-rows-to-display-different-popups

Comment: If nobody gets there before me, I will solve that for you in about 8 hours with a workable online example :)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the post and update the answer.